# Recursively Visiting a node in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am learning about different ways of traversing a binary tree. I have a few questions about this.  I've seen such pseudocode for inorder traversal (for example):

```
 InOrder (a node N)
{
   if N is not empty
   {
     InOrder (N's left child)
     visit N
     InOrder (N's right child)
   }
}
```

What does it mean to "visit" the node? Does this just mean to print it out? Also, how does the alogirthm keep track of the nodes it's already visited? Does it use a queue such is used in breadth-first traversal?

Thank you

Comment: I found this really good YouTube video on recursive calling and the call stack.  This clarified my question above. Here is the link: http://youtu.be/k0bb7UYy0pY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"visit" means do something with it. At the end of the day you want to do something with every node, not just to go through the all of them.

Algorithms "keeps track" of what is visited in callstack, in function arguments. I.e. if you ask "where's the information?" — information is there. No additional storage is required — that's the beauty of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

To visit a node is to apply some action to it, an example of which could be printing it.

One such implementation of a tree-traversal function would accept an action, a function object, that should be called for each node. An example in C might look like this:

```
typedef void (*node_func)(node_t *);

void in_order (node_t *root, node_func f) {
    if (root) {
        in_order(root->left);
        f(root);              // "visit" the node
        in_order(root->right);
    }
}
```

And perhaps you implement a printing function:

```
void print_node (node_t *node) {
    printf("Node: %s", node->id); // or whatever your node looks like
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
void print_tree(node_t *root) {
    in_order(root, &print_node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Visit" usually refers to accessing the memory location of that "node". Printing include accessing the "node" in memory. This particular algorithm does not keep track of visited nodes. It utilizes recursive calls. If you're not familiar with **recursion** I suggest you read about it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: To clarify, this particular algorithm does not have to allocate extra space e.g. explicitly allocate a data structure for keeping track of visited nodes because like @kirilloid said, this information is kept in the callstack =] More about he callstack here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Answer (score 0):

By visit I think it is just talking about either printing it or using it in some way. In order traversal is different from breadth first I think that watching some youtube videos of the in order traversal will help you understand better than trying to explain.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9870BucMg64
Here is a quick video that is an example of in order that is fairly clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive way of traversing a binary tree.

"Visit" the node is ambiguous as this is a pseudo-code, so it could just mean to print it out, or to execute a specific set of code.

Recursion is normally handled by adding it to the execution stack.
Both non-recursive and recursive use similar amounts of memory. But access times on stacks are trivial because they're in logical executive order. So in this particular example, the left child is recursed, then the node, and then the right child.

So in the example would be:

```
                               A
                             /   \
                            B     C
                           / \   / \
                          D   E F   G
```

Since it's an inorder algorithm, it will be executed:
Visit D, Visit B, Visit E, Visit A, Visit F, Visit C, Visit G.

Comment: wait wouldn't it be traversed D,B,E,A,F,C,G for in order?